# Is every triangle with 3 rational angles (in degrees) similar to one with 3 integer-length sides?

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

The same way right triangles have pythagorean triples, does every non-right class of similar triangles also have some integer triples, if we say that all the angles have to be rational numbers in degrees?

Are there other interesting results about integer triples if we relax/tighten the restrictions on the angle values?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle

Comment: A more interesting question if any integer triangle can have rational angles (in degrees).  Equilateral triangles are examples, but are there any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider a triangle with angles 30, 60, 90.

Comment: Even better, the triangle with angles 45, 45, 90 is the one to have so disappointed the Pythagoreans that its hypotenuse was not rational that, legends say, the discoverer of this fact was murdered!

Comment: Ahhh right, I forgot pythagorean triples don't even apply to every kind of right triangle. Thanks.